# Where can I get translation of Ganesha Aarti

Tags: ganesha

Can someone provide me exact translation of Ganesha Aarti in English?
How it came into existence?
Also since when Lord Ganesha is known as Vighnaharta? Is there any story behind it?

Comment: You have to be specific about the aarti you are talking about there are various aarti in hindi, marathi,tamil, telegu etc.

Comment: Can you answer why Lord Ganesh given the name Vighnaharta?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question it's just as easy as find it on Google [Click here to learn how to!](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ganpati%20aarti%20with%20english%20translation):

- Following is the popular marathi aarti [Sukhkarta dukhharta (Marathi to English Translation)](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/ganapati-aarti-sukhkarta-dukhharta-with-english-translation-free-download-mp3)

  - This aarti was created by [Samarth Ramdas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samarth_Ramdas)

and another popular we hear in most pandals is

- [Jai ganesh Jai ganesh (Hindi to English Translation](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_ganesha-jai_ganesh_jai_ganesh_aarti.php)
  (I'm not sure of origin for this!)

Still looking forward for the story of the title "vighnaharta"...